# php - bind_param inside foreach() not correctly passing

Tags: php, foreach, mysqli

I'm sure this is a duplicate, but I've tried several different things on the site here and none of them are working for me.  I'm calling my function in php, sending $mysqli connection, the $clientID, and the array of $tagFields to upload.

It's 'working', but the values are always null.  I've put echo "$tagName" inside the foreach, and it's reading it, but not sending it up to the database.  $clientID, however, IS passing information.  So basically all it does is upload consistently blank rows into my database.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
function tagRefresh($mysqli,$clientID,$tagFields) {
    $stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
    $query = "INSERT INTO client_tags (client_id,tag_category) VALUES (?,?) ";
    $stmt->prepare($query);
    foreach($tagFields as $tagName) {
        $stmt->bind_param('is',$clientID,$tagName);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

some sample values for $tagFields:

```
$tagFields[0] = "Regional";$tagFields[1] = "Automotive";$tagFields[2] = "Maintenance";
```

Comment: I believe `bind_param` only binds to a reference of the variable. So, since your `foreach` is resetting `$tagName` upon each iteration, the binding fails. Unfortunately, I can't find a `bindValue` (PDO) equivalent in mysqli. Also, you'll want to `execute` only once after your `foreach` is complete.

Comment: Check this example; http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php#107200

Comment: Your code works for me.

Comment: @MiroslavStopka, what version of php/mysql/apache are you running?

Comment: @MDWar PHP Version 5.3.8, MySQL: 5.5.16 , Apache Version Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0e PHP/5.3.8 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1. Btw check your table client_tags  (column attributes ...)

Comment: @MiroslavStopka I threw in a billion different error reporting things, and found the problem; the primary key for the table was set to the client_id, instead of the tag_id.  This DB has been such trouble because of stupid stuff like that from the original developer...

Comment: @MDWar Congratz :D So the problem was table indeed.

Comment: @MiroslavStopka with this particular DB, I'm starting to realize that's the answer to every problem I've had...

Answer (score 1):

Note **[mysqli_stmt::bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)** bind the reference of the variables.
Try the below:

```
function tagRefresh($mysqli,$clientID,$tagFields) {
    $stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
    $query = "INSERT INTO client_tags (client_id,tag_category) VALUES (?,?) ";
    $stmt->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('is', $clientID, $tagName);
    foreach($tagFields as $tagName) {
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

execute() shouldn't be situated inside the foreach.

Comment: But it can't hurt either ;)

Comment: unless the intent is to execute it multiple times

Comment: Why? How would you suggest executing this multiple times without a loop?

Comment: So, don't use prepared statements? That seems like a bad idea.

Comment: No, it's not ... the problem was only about the execute() method !
So you can prepare the statement the way you want, using a loop or not, but the execute() method must be called only one time.

Comment: Why _must_ it be called only once? Dynamically building a query as you suggest prevents the use of prepared statements, which means it may be less efficient and less secure. Repeatedly executing the statement was exactly the intention; that's where prepared statements can exhibit greater efficiency. There's nothing inherently wrong about doing so. To the contrary, in the proper scenarios it may be advisable. If the data is all internal and does not include user input, building it as you suggest may be fine. If user input _is_ involved, then I would certainly use prepared statements.

Answer (score -1):

Among with a myriad of problems associated with the database (including the client_id being the primary key), I've rebuilt the formula like this:

```
function tagRefresh($mysqli,$clientID,$tagFields) {
    $query = "DELETE FROM client_tags WHERE client_id = '" . $clientID . "'"; //we have to delete the old ones every time
    if(!$mysqli->query($query)) {
        echo $mysqli->error;
    }

    if($tagFields != '') { //see if data was sent
        $tags = array();
        foreach($tagFields as $tag) {
            $tags[] = "('" . (int) $clientID . "', '" . $tag ."')"; //build an array
        }
        $query = "INSERT INTO client_tags (client_id,tag) VALUES " . implode(',', $tags) . " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE client_id = " . $clientID;
        if(!$mysqli->query($query)) {
            echo $mysqli->error; //drop errors, will attach this later
        }
    }
}
```

This formats to something like this:

```
INSERT INTO client_tags (client_id,tag) VALUES ('1234','mechanical'),('1234','regional'),('1234','service') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE client_id = '1234';
```

The ON DUPLICATE part is important because for some reason the client_id is set to primary key.  I'm gonna have to talk to the app guys and see if this matters to them.

Unfortunately, bind_param isn't being used, but this is a admin panel access only for company employees only, and now that this is working I'm giving them autocomplete boxes to reference existing values.