# Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Okay I know that there are countless questions about the same issue in the forum, but none of them helped me. I get the error mentioned in my title when executing what's below in my php file:

```
// connection established and $stmt initiated with mysqli_stmt_init( $conn )
$sql = "SELECT * FROM my_contacts
       WHERE asking_id=? AND responding_name=? AND status = 'waiting'";

mysqli_stmt_prepare( $stmt, $sql ); // always successful

$data_for_queries = array(
           array( $asking_id, $responding_name ),
           array( $responding_id, $asking_name )
         );

foreach ( $data_for_queries as $data_content ) {
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param( $stmt, "is", $data_content[0], $data_content[1] );
  // echo mysqli_error( $conn );
  mysqli_stmt_execute( $stmt );
  //...
}
```

When var_dumping my `$data_for_queries`, I get exactly the array I expect. What's wrong?!

UPDATE: My query actually gets executed and does what I want as it's written here, but it keeps returning the mentioned error..... ?!

UPDATE 2: This script is triggered with an ajax call on a button click. Weirdly, when I run it once, it gets executed, but I get the error as mentioned as the response from the server. However, when I click on another button that triggers exactly the same script execution again, without refreshing the page, everything works WITHOUT any error message from the server.. I'm really confused about this. So don't misunderstand me here, I keep getting the error message coming from the server as described in the title.

**UPDATE 3**: Alright so now I commented out the foreach loop, and just attempted to execute the statement with the elements of the first subarray bound, by replacing the `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` function line in my code with the following one:

`mysqli_stmt_bind_param( $stmt, "is", $data_for_queries[0][0], $data_for_queries[0][1] );`

and that worked perfectly, without errors returned (but yeah only for half of the records I yielded with my `$data_for_queries` array). From this I conclude that it indeed seems to be a problem to call `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` inside the foreach loop, but why is that so?? Isn't it, aside security, one of the purposes of prepared statements to work with variable values inside loops ..? And after all, how can I make my code work without errors..? It can't be that I really HAVE TO code EVERY SINGLE run using the same statement but different values over and over again right..? There must be a feasible way to shorten this into a loop I guess...?

Comment: Put `$data_content[0]` into a variable and put the variable in the bind function and put the prepare outsite the loop

Comment: I'm not sure but might also try `as &$data_content) {` never tried it.

Comment: already tried, nothing changed.. I also just echoed out the two array elements at the beginning of the for loop (at the start of the iteration), and I get exactly what I expect them to be...

Comment: Inside the loop you tried `$v1 = $data_content[0]; $v2 = $data_content[1];` and then used `$v1` and `$v2` in the prepare?

Comment: yessir, exactly tried that already..

Comment: @AbraCadaver passing the array by reference also didn't work..

Comment: The problem is NOT in this code which makes this question off topic

Comment: @YourCommonSense please consider what I wrote in "Update 3", I don't feel that my question is necessarily off topic, it seems to be related to the foreach loop indeed. If you may know the solution...

Comment: May be the problem is coming from some other code.

Comment: First, thanks for reconsidering and taking back downvotes, to whoever did this :). To answer your comment, I didn't change absolutely nothing except the modifications commented in update 3, so I really cannot figure out the problem. I came across this post before writing my question, and it seems to be the closest concern in terms of similarity, but still didn't help me to figure out a feasible solution.. It may help anyone reading my post to figure out a solution, so I wanted to copy it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775864/php-bind-param-inside-foreach-not-correctly-passing/15776002

Comment: It is no better than the answer you get here, and misleading as well. Your problem is not in this code.

Comment: do you have any conditions inside the real foreach loop?

Comment: yep a lot, like ```if ( mysqli_num_rows( $result ) === 1 ) {...}``` , ```while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {...}``` (the classics to handle database query results), and later another ```mysqli_stmt_prepare()``` (to execute another prepared statement of another query which can't be done simultaneously), ```mysqli_stmt_bind_param()``` and ```mysqli_stmt_execute()``` (they return no errors and seem to work appropriately).

Answer (score -1):

You should place the bind outside the loop and assign the variables in your loop and then execute

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param( $stmt, "is", $value_1, $value_2 );

foreach ( $data_for_queries as $data_content ) {
  $value_1 = $data_content[0];
  $value_2 = $data_content[1];
  // echo mysqli_error( $conn );
  mysqli_stmt_execute( $stmt );
  //...
}
```

Comment: unfortunately that also didn't work.. I'm really wondering what's going on. When I did this it said that my result with my ```mysqli_stmt_get_result( $stmt );``` function is a boolean (false I guess).

Comment: That means your query has an error but the bind worked.

Comment: well I adapted exactly as you said and didn't change anything in the query in comparison to what's written above, so I doubt that..

Comment: also, how can a query have an error and its parameter binding and execution work successfully..?

Comment: There is not a single reason for this approach to help anything.

Comment: @YourCommonSense okay from your comment to my question and down here, you think that my code is 100% correct as copied into my question above? Nevertheless, when I do as stated in this answer, I only get ``` mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given``` as response from the server. Otherwise I get what's written in my title PLUS that, so it seems to make it better. Although the error thus may not be in my copied code; is there any classic mistake you know about which leads to this kind of error? Given your huge reputation you may know stuff, its driving me nuts

Comment: @DevelJoe the only classic mistake is obviously when the number of placeholders in the query doesn't match the number of variables in bind_param. Which is NOT the case in this code.

Comment: Yeah I checked my code like 56724576 times about these kinds of mistakes before pasting it here, to try to avoid wasting anyone's time as far as possible ^^